# how to preserve grunt task arguments when wrapping it

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I am using the grunt-release plugin. Normally in a shell you use commands like `grunt release`, `grunt release:minor`, `grunt release:major`, etc. I am composing another task that wraps the release task:

```
grunt.registerTask('custom-release', ['task1', 'release', 'task2']);
```

Hence when you call `grunt custom-release:major`, is there any chance I can invoke my release task to get invoked as `release:major`?

Else am I forced to register tasks conforming to each of the grunt-release options?:

```
grunt.registerTask('custom-release-major', ['task1', 'release:major', 'task2']);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
grunt.registerTask('custom-release', 'my awesome custom-release', function(type) {
  switch(type){
    case 'major':
      grunt.task.run(['task1', 'release:major', 'task2'])
      break;
    case 'minor':
    default:
      grunt.task.run(['task1', 'release:minor', 'task2'])
      break;
  }
});
```

now you can use

- `grunt custom-release:major`
- `grunt custom-release:minor`
- `grunt custom-release`